# How to remove apps from my list in the Windows 8 store?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, windows-store, windows-store-app

I installed Windows 8 on my laptop to play around with it. I downloaded quite a lot of apps, even ones that I don't like. The ones I didn't like I uninstalled.

Now, I installed Windows 8 on my desktop. When I went to the store and go to "Your Apps" so that I can redownload some of the apps that I like, it shows a ton of the apps I consider "junk". Is there any way to remove them from that list? Otherwise, the "Your Apps" section can become very useless if the apps I want are in a mess of hundreds of apps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you can't. Afaik, Microsoft doesn't allow people to hide purchases like Apple does on its app stores. You can only create a new Microsoft account which will clear all the apps from the list.

Once you download any app from the Windows Store, it gets added to your purchase history (even if it is free).

This has one advantage. Suppose, an app is released for free and you download it. Later, the developer increases the price of the app. You don't need to purchase the app because you already downloaded it when it was free. Also, you will receive free updates for the app forever.

Comment: This wouldn't be so bad if most of the apps, even in 2014, weren't crap. But there's so many fake/scam apps, that just by checking to see if it's legit, I permanently have this crap listed forever in my account.

Comment: @MichaelGG http://www.pcworld.com/article/2599596/microsoft-finally-cracks-down-on-deceptive-windows-store-crap-apps.html

Comment: it's simply not true. Last week, there were fake Netflix and HBO GO apps in the store. There's still a fake Showtime Channel one. Microsoft refuses to remove them unless the TM owner contacts them. They're perfectly content to keep that junk in there. *Twice* I've gotten Netflix to contact MS and remove the fake Netflix apps. They came back, even after their supposed push to clean it up. Someone's bonus is tied to the broken metric "# of apps in store".

Comment: It has no advantage since you cannot remove the app from removed apps list. there will be an advantage if you got a warning that you understand and you accept after which app is removed permanently or not if you consider to install it some day in future

Answer (score 0):

Remove this device name from your Microsoft account. Then, your device will not show those apps which were installed previously. Now you can see no apps installed in your account.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots? I do not know see where to remove it.